I in linux system I geting many same exported path variable
In my ubuntu system I getting same env variable many times
This is the output of echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | less command in zsh shell
/opt/some/bin  <<<
/Users/pritam/Developer/system_script
/usr/bin
/bin
/opt/some/bin  <<<
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/some/bin  <<<


As you can see <<< are the many duplicate env PATH variable path

Note
I have checked my .zshenv .zshrc .bashrc .bash_profile .profile files there is no any PATH variable exported as /opt/some/bin
Can some one tell me how can I find the file form where these PATH values are exported so I can remove them

Is that really the output of the exact command echo "$PATH" or have you done some post-processing? Why are there newlines there? Also, why is zsh relevant? What shell do you use? Is it bash, zsh or something else? Have you also checked .profile? What is the output of grep -RH /opt/some/bin ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/ /etc/environment 2> /dev/null? (please add the answer to your question)

Look at /etc/environment, that's the starting PATH.  Then look in your .profile to see what gets added to PATH (like .local/bin, etc.). PATH gets inherited, so should only be done once. Changing PATH in .bashrc can be done, but .bashrc is executed a lot, and care needs to be taken not to execute stuff more than once. Likewise a script you run that changes PATH, multiple runs result in multiple modifications unless you take explicit care to avoid that.

Why not search for PATH assignments with grep -RH 'PATH='  ...?

Read 6.2 Bash Startup Files

look in /etc/profile and any file that it sources (using source or . commands).


When dealing with "colon-separated" lists (PATH is one example) I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935
The addpath function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. delpath -n deletes all non-existent directories from a path. uniqpath removes duplicate entries. listpath lists a path.
You can get the pathfunc.tgz file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Please post the scripts here. As it stands, this isn't an answer since if the links break it becomes useless. In any case, the question here isn't how to add to the PATH while avoiding duplicates, it is "how did these things end up in my path?" so the scripts you link to, while helpful, cannot provide an answer.

@terdon The scripts are not my creation; I feel uncomfortable redistributing them; I will not support them;they come as a gzip compressed Tar archive. There isn't a way to attach a .tgz to my answer, unless I use uuencode or shar, which seems to subvert AskUbuntu's purpose (It's a Q&A site, not a software distribution site), and would associate my name with one of the most baroque,  idiotic, non-functional software distribution schemes ever. End of rant.

While the scripts probably is useful, you don't answer the questioon: How to figure out why some items appear multiple times.
